# Queries to get Files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get all the son files in a parent folder in Google Drive.

For this, I am using the ID of the parent folder and this query " `'1234567' in parents` ". Where '1234567 'is the ID of the parent folder.

The ID is correct, because when I try to get its information on: 'https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it' all the file information appears me.

I am using java, this is the code:

```
  List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
      String query="'"+FileId+"' in parents";
        Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ(query);

        do {
          try {
            FileList files = request.execute();

            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
          }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
                 request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

The Query would be syntactically correct?

I not get any child file, however if I use a query stating "mimetype" (`request = service.files().list().setq("mimeType = 'application / vnd.google-apps.folder'")`) , I get results.

Thanks in advance and regards!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on http logging and compare the http sent from your app with the http in Try It

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(yourFullClassName).setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.All);
```